# chain conflict with pgfdeclarelayer

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

See this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0 and 0]
\pgfdeclarelayer{background} % comment this line works
{[start chain=C1]
    \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e,f}
    \node[draw,minimum size=1.5em,outer sep=0,on chain=C1] (N\i) {\i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! Package tikz Error: Unknown chain ``C1''.
```

The code can not pass compile but if I comment out the pgfdeclarelayer line, it works fine.

Does that means pgfdeclarelayer conflict with chain package? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't conflict with \pgfdeclarelayer - you would get a similar error with lots of other commands in this place as your syntax is wrong.

The problem is that the scopes library allows you to use braces as a shorthand for a scope only in quite specific places -- and after a command is not such a place. (It would work if you add a \path command).

You should use [start chain C1] as option to a scope:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0 and 0]
\pgfdeclarelayer{background} % comment this line works
\begin{scope}[start chain=C1]
    \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e,f}
    \node[draw,minimum size=1.5em,outer sep=0,on chain=C1] (N\i) {\i};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer, but why it work if without the pgfdeclarelayer line?

Comment: Because you are then using the scopes shorthand directly after tikzpicture and then it works. I added a short explanation.

Comment: In general, I think it is better to declare the layers before starting the `tikzpicture`, perhaps even in the preamble of the document.